# insert variable in simple quotes | select-string -argumentlist '$variable'

Tags: powershell, variables, arguments, double-quotes, single-quotes

I would like to insert a variable into simple quotes of a "ArgumentList" for start-process, but it doesn't do the job.

this is what i expected to work :

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:/PATH/application.exe" -ArgumentList '-I "C:/PATH/$VAR1"','-arg2 "$VAR2"'`

the arguments are stricts and the manual command would look like this in the terminal :

```
cctk.exe -I "inputfile" --ValSetupPwd=password
```

Thank's for the help !

Comment: You have to use `"` to quote the string: `-ArgumentList "-I ""C:/PATH/$VAR1""","-arg2 ""$VAR2"""`

Comment: Alternatively, pass keywords separate as `-ArgumentList "-I", "C:/PATH/$VAR1", "-arg2", "$VAR2"`. For your particular use case, something like `Start-Process cctk.exe -ArgumentList "-I", """inputfile""", "--ValSetupPwd=password"`